# When i play a wav file with sample rate 250000Hz with omxplayer, it seam that th omxplayer is hang up in some place

Tags: omxplayer

When i play a wav file with sample rate 250000Hz with omxplayer in my pi 3b+, it seems that the omxplayer is hang up in some place.

i got the error log as below, can anybody explain the meaning of the error code of 0x80001005.
i had post a new issue in github, does anyone solve this issue?

https://github.com/popcornmix/omxplayer/issues/724

Thanks!

the error log as below

```
15:31:54 T:2041236533  [OMXCore.cpp][SetParameter][1153]   ERROR: COMXCoreComponent::SetParameter - OMX.broadcom.audio_mixer failed with omx_err(0x80001005)
15:31:54 T:2041236566  [OMXAudio.cpp][PortSettingsChanged][149]   ERROR: COMXAudio::PortSettingsChanged - error m_omx_mixer SetParameter omx_err(0x80001005)
15:31:54 T:2041236591  [OMXAudio.cpp][AddPackets][982]   ERROR: COMXAudio::AddPackets - error PortSettingsChanged omx_err(0x00000000)
```

It seems that there is a infinity loop in main function, the same log print 386 times.

```
2:46:01 T:18446744071594686822  [omxplayer.cpp][main][1697]   DEBUG: Normal M:0 (A:1114112 V:0) P:0 A:1.11 V:0.00/T:0.20 (0,0,1,1) A:16% V:0% (0.99,4.11)
12:46:01 T:18446744071594708874  [omxplayer.cpp][main][1697]   DEBUG: Normal M:0 (A:1114112 V:0) P:0 A:1.11 V:0.00/T:0.20 (0,0,1,1) A:29% V:0% (0.99,4.11)
12:46:01 T:18446744071594731745  [omxplayer.cpp][main][1697]   DEBUG: Normal M:0 (A:1114112 V:0) P:0 A:1.11 V:0.00/T:0.20 (0,0,1,1) A:45% V:0% (0.99,4.11)
12:46:01 T:18446744071594754692  [omxplayer.cpp][main][1697]   DEBUG: Normal M:0 (A:1114112 V:0) P:0 A:1.11 V:0.00/T:0.20 (0,0,1,1) A:62% V:0% (0.99,4.11)
12:46:01 T:18446744071594777540  [omxplayer.cpp][main][1697]   DEBUG: Normal M:0 (A:1114112 V:0) P:0 A:1.11 V:0.00/T:0.20 (0,0,1,1) A:79% V:0% (0.99,4.11)
12:46:01 T:18446744071594800498  [omxplayer.cpp][main][1697]   DEBUG: Normal M:0 (A:1114112 V:0) P:0 A:1.11 V:0.00/T:0.20 (0,0,1,1) A:95% V:0% (0.99,4.11)
12:46:01 T:18446744071594826330  [omxplayer.cpp][main][1697]   DEBUG: Normal M:0 (A:1114112 V:0) P:0 A:1.11 V:0.00/T:0.20 (0,0,1,1) A:99% V:0% (0.99,4.11)
12:46:09 T:18446744071602844181  [OMXClock.cpp][OMXStop][211]   DEBUG: Previous line repeats 386 times.
```

and i found the definition from the firmware code:

`hardfp/opt/vc/include/IL/OMX_Core.h: OMX_ErrorBadParameter = (OMX_S32) 0x80001005,`

in hardfp/opt/vc/include/IL/OMX_Core.h, it seems that the error code meanings parameters is not valid, but it doesn't tell me which one is valid.

```
/** One or more parameters were not valid */
OMX_ErrorBadParameter = (OMX_S32) 0x80001005,
```

Comment: But 250k sampling rate is way too high.  Did you mean 25k?

Comment: Nobody knows what the issue is.  You need to provide far more information.  At least give an example audio file you can't play.

Comment: @Ming Ding, upload your .wav file so that everybody can try oxmplaying it.

Comment: Technically you can record .wav's at 250KHz but I do not think it is very common.

Comment: sorry to replay so late. i am try my best to solve this problem with diffenent way. My log file and wav file is here. https://github.com/popcornmix/omxplayer/issues/724 @tlfong01

Comment: I found that, in OMXAudio.cpp, line 139, just set the max sample rate to 192000, th code is ```m_pcm_output.nSamplingRate = std::min(std::max((int)m_pcm_output.nSamplingRate, 8000), 192000);```, but when i change it to 250000, nothing happened, the error as before.

Comment: @goldilocks. Actually speaking, 250KHz is not common in our life and human beings can not hear it. But i am impressed by this idea, and i am in the seam situation. So i am try to find a solution to solve this problem.https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/6mvd4l/raspberry_pi_noob_battling_cats_with_ultrasonic/

Comment: BTW: T0000001.zip is the ultrasonic wav file with sample rate is 250KKz, and the error log in omxplayer.log
And omxplayer.wzzhn.log is the common log when i play a common wav file.@tlfong01

Comment: @Ming Ding, Oh my goodness, so yours is not a sound file but a ultrasound file for your super dog or aliens to listen.  I know WAV means Waveform AUDIO File.  Anyway, I unzipped to a 11 seconds file and used my Win10 Media Player to play it.  My cheapie speaker did not "speak" anything.  I need a ulltrasound speaker to "speak" it.  I vaguely remember I once used my 50MHz scope to display audio.  But even if I see the wave form, how to use my stupid human ears to listen?  You remind me that I did once use a scope to watch my ultrasolund senor's echoes which are indeed ultrasound freq.

Comment: @Ming Ding, I did not use my omxplayer to play your ultrasound file because it might explode.  I vaguely remember that .WAV file is a very raw data file, without any compression.  So we can easily use a scope or ADC to display or recover the aliens' speeches and google translate them!:)

Comment: Supper time.  See you late evening or tomorrow!

Comment: @MingDing That's what I meant by *possible*, lol.  The spec allows for values into the gigahertz -- if anyone really uses them that way, though, it is very unlikely it is for sound recording.  WAV is a lossless format for recording waves and apparently have been used for (eg.) storing circuit traces: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV#Non-audio_data

Comment: @Ming Ding, but cats can only hear up to 60kHz, and if your next door cat, if white, may be deaf: (1) https://www.cathealth.com/behavior/how-and-why/1328-how-well-cats-hear. Or you can consider this ultrasound cat repeller: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mv13QDct9OY. :)

Comment: @tlfong01 what you just mentioned is very interesting. I am try my best to find why the Omxplayer is in infinity loop in main function now. That confused me.

Comment: @Ming Ding, for troubleshooting, first thing first, I would suggest you to lower the frequency from 250kHz to 1kHz, and see if parameter setting error message disappears.

Comment: @tlfong01 when I play a wav file with sample 44100 Hz, it works perfectly.

Comment: @Ming Ding, Well, then you can test the omxplayer program limit by increasing the frequency to 100kHz, then 500kHz, ... If I am the omxplayer program writer, of course I will flag error if input parameter is ridiculously too high, even cats can't hear! :)